# fetch data from data base -inheritance PHP

Tags: php, sql

I have two classes each correspond to a table in an sql database.

Class `Person` and class `Admin` which is a child class of `Person`. In others words:

```
class Admin extends Person {}
```

Table Person is constructed like this:

```
id, name, salary
```

Table Admin like this:

```
id, login, password.
```

I need to fetch data from Admin but with all information (like inheritance or tables joined), I mean with:

`id, name, salary, login, password`

How can i do this please?

Comment: Are you using a SQL database?

Comment: Do you know how do a join in a query?

Comment: Yes i know it ..I was juste wondering if i can make it through inheritance , i mean a method in parent and the other in child

Comment: Updating to phrase the question to meet OP intent.